# Make an array of objects from two objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to make an array of objects from 2 objects: id's object and values object.

I can't understand how to sort through both objects at the same time and compare their keys to make a result array of objects

```
id: {
 value1: 1,
 value2: 2,
 value3: 3,
};
values: {
 value1: 11,
 value2: 22,
 value3: 33,
};
```

The key names of both objects may be the same.
Need to have something like that:

```
result:[
 {1: 11},
 {2: 22},
 {3: 33},
]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect pairs of `id` and `values` and then render a new array with objects.

```js
var data = { id: { value1: 1, value2: 2, value3: 3 }, values: { value1: 11, value2: 22, value3: 33 } },
    result = Array.from(
        Object
            .entries(data)
            .reduce(
                (m, [l, o]) => Object
                    .entries(o)
                    .reduce((n, [k, v]) => n.set(k, Object.assign({ [l]: v }, n.get(k))), m),
                 new Map
            )
            .values(),
        ({ id, values }) => ({ [id]: values })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Does it need to be that complicated for such a straightforward task? I am genuinely asking, because I would like to know if there's an edge case missing in my approach.

Comment: you are right, if the inner keys are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let result = [];
Object.keys(id).forEach((key)=>{
    let temp = {};
    temp[id[key]] = values[key];
    result.push(temp)
})
```

This will give you the output as you mentioned, but I don't understand why you would want `result` to be an array instead of an object.

Comment: It must be an array because of back end requirements. But i can collect data from form only in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are the same in `id` and `value` you can simply map over the keys of one of them and use the key to get the corresponding values from each object:

```js
let data = {id: {value1: 1,value2: 2,value3: 3,},values: {value1: 11,value2: 22,value3: 33,}}

let result = Object.keys(data.id).map(k => ({[data.id[k]]: data.values[k]}))
console.log(result)
```